# Curving/warping views with CoreAnimation or OpenGL for carousel effect

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uiscrollview, core-animation, quartz-graphics

Right now I'm populating a UIScrollView with a series of views. The views need to be warped to make the UIScrollView appear like a carousel. In other words when the user scrolls it needs to be like a circle. I've never done anything quite like this before, but I'm assuming CoreAnimation is out of the question and OpenGL needs to be used. If this is possible with CoreAnimation or Quartz then I really just need a sample on how to warp the views and I can figure the rest out myself but I'm not familiar with OpenGL.

[image]

Comment: not 100% sure, but I think that you may be able to apply a CATransform3D to your view's layer property.

Comment: Yeah, I read a bit about this but I've never really used that before. Do you know of any samples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, it is a bit tricky to get the values right. The way to give a view perspective is by manipulating it's layer transform. I have used the following method to achieve the transfor for a similar effect:

```
-(CATransform3D)makeTransformForAngle:(CGFloat)angle from:(CATransform3D)start{

    CATransform3D transform = start;


    // the following two lines are the key to achieve the perspective effect
CATransform3D persp = CATransform3DIdentity;
    persp.m34 = 1.0 / -1000;

    transform = CATransform3DConcat(transform, persp);
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    return transform;
}
```

This was done to create a "flip page" animation, so you may need to adapt. To use it, do the following:

```
flip_page.layer.transform = [self makeTransformForAngle:angle from:CATransform3DIdentity];
```

where flip_page is a UIView. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! My main issue is with warping the individual views as shown above. Do you know how to go about this?

Comment: I see. For that, of course, a linear transform is not enough. I'm sure you can create the mesh in OpenGL and slap the texture. But that seems like an overkill. I hope this question gets a clever answer ;)

Comment: This allows me to add perspective to the individual views, which is needed. However, they also need to be warped.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to warp the views, you'll either need OpenGL or you could use Core Animation's CAShapLayer which allows you to specify a bezier path which can have this curve in it. But keep in mind that this curving you're seeing is likely just an optical illusion (though in your image above it looks like an actual curve). If you get enough rectangles with the correct y axis rotation in a row, I think you can come up with the effect you're looking for with straight Core Animation. I'm pretty sure that's how things are implemented in the Core Animation demos Apple provided a couple years ago. Here's a screenshot from the video from that presentation:
[image: Core Animation Layer Warping]

I messed around with the transform of a view's layer a little bit and came up with this:

```
- (IBAction)sliderDidChange:(id)sender
{
  CGFloat value = [(UISlider*)sender value];
  CGFloat xOff = value - 0.5;

  CATransform3D trans = CATransform3DIdentity;
  trans.m34 = 1.0f / -1000.0f;

  trans = CATransform3DRotate(trans, degreesToRadians(xOff * -25.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  trans = CATransform3DTranslate(trans, 0.0f, 0.0f, 900.0f * fabs(xOff));
  [[frameView layer] setTransform:trans];

  CGPoint center= [frameView center];
  [frameView setCenter:CGPointMake(1024.0 * value, center.y)];
}
```

I threw together [a demo project](http://www.cimgf.com/files/FlimStrip.zip) that shows how the rotation works in response to a slider. It doesn't use a scroll view so you would have to adapt it, but I think you can track the current scroll offset and apply the transform accordingly. Not sure if it will help but there it is.